# How to alternatively repeat json data in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to alternatively repeat the json data. I've data like below:

JSON:

```
  {
       "birds":{
          "birdInfo":[
             {
                "name":"parrot",
                "color":"green"
             },
             {
                "name":"peacock",
                "color":"green"
             }
          ]
       },
       "animals":{
          "animalInfo":[
             {
                "name":"lion",
                "designation":"king"
             },
             {
                "name":"lioness",
                "designation":"queen"
             }
          ]
       }
    }
```

In my controller:

```
    $scope.birdInfo = response.birds.birdInfo;
    $scope.animalInfo = response.animals.animalInfo;
```

In my View:

```
 <div ng-repeat="bird in birdInfo">
   {{bird.name}}
 </div>

 <div ng-repeat="animal in animalInfo">
   {{animal.name}}
 </div>
```

What I want:

I want data to be display like:

Scenario 1 : one alternative repeat item

```
  parrot
  LION
  peacock
  LIONESS
```

Scenario 1 : two alternative repeat items

```
  parrot
  peacock
  LION
  LIONESS
  crow
  dove
  TIGER
  ELEPHANT
```

How to do that in angular?

Here is the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/hN7odUF3MLJe4Ad9IBNM?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function to merge your 2 arrays into a 3rd array with the order you need, and then just iterate over that in html.

It would look something like this, if an array is longer you can append the items at the end:

```js
 function merge(first, second) {
   var merged = [];
   var shortest = Math.min(first.length, second.length);
   for (var i = 0; i < shortest; i++) {
     merged.push(first[i]);
     merged.push(second[i]);
   }

   if (first.length != second.length) {
     var left = first.length > second.length ? first.slice(second.length) : second.slice(first.length);
     console.log(left);
     merged = merged.concat(left);
   }
   return merged;
 }
```

Check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b3NATpv26mhz06RnEaEz?p=preview) to see it working.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will do.

Comment: Javascript already give you a function to concatenate arrays as I pointed in my answer. You do not need to create another one...

Comment: @vinagreti concat does solve the 2nd problem he asked, not the 1st one though. :)

Comment: I wouldn't assume that all arrays have the same length, even if it's the case in the example.

Comment: I agree, but he did not specify what should happen if the arrays have different lengths :)

Comment: Sorry guys. For not mentioning it. Of course my array length is obviously different. Can u give me some glue to go through this? http://plnkr.co/edit/G9DPNU1wm3NlBiYpHL5v?p=preview

Comment: what should the result be in that case? the items that can't be merged are appended at the end?

Comment: yes. If the merging is not possible it can append at the end.

Comment: @RajagopalSubramanian I updated the answer and the plunker example. :)

Comment: I think it's not working if the length of first array is larger than second. http://plnkr.co/edit/MH1VRzv2TxtgDWAwch1y?p=preview

Comment: @RajagopalSubramanian indeed, I forgot to update the actual merge to take into account that the array lengths are different. The array should happen on the min length of the 2 arrays, I updated the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @RajagopalSubramanian since I saw a lot of people trying to post a more angulary solution to this. you can make the merge function to be a filter and use it like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/kkxrkRzWNqBe3q89huXy?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can concat the two arrays inside ng-repeat as below

```
ng-repeat="birdOrAnimal in concatenatedData = (birdInfo.concat(animalInfo))"
```

I've just updated your plunker with this.

http://plnkr.co/edit/uOj2XrgYKzLXpurzp8Mv

Comment: can you post the link ?

Comment: Up vote because it's even more simpler using a directive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

http://plnkr.co/edit/bV0Bd6LINmzcjQodC9Cj?p=preview

In this approach, I'm creating a repeater that just uses the $index value to count through the objects:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index">
    <p>{{birdInfo[$index].name}} - {{birdInfo[$index].color}}</p>
    <p>{{animalInfo[$index].name}} - {{animalInfo[$index].designation}}</p>
</div>
```

The length is counted by the bird length.

```
$scope.number = $scope.birdInfo.length;
      $scope.getNumber = function() {
      return new Array($scope.number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
`<div ng-repeat="bird in birdInfo" ng-if="birdInfo.length>=animalInfo.length">
   <div>{{bird.name}} - {{bird.color}}</div>
   <div>{{animalInfo[$index].name}} - {{animalInfo[$index].designation}}</div>
 </div>
 <div ng-repeat="ani in animalInfo" ng-if="birdInfo.length<animalInfo.length">
   <div>{{birdInfo[$index].name}} - {{birdInfo[$index].color}}</div>
   <div>{{ani.name}} - {{ani.designation}}</div>
 </div>`
```

[see this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c1n5zYkNXd2GtMKJOr2g?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

It's more about algorithms than AngularJS.

You can [Array concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) your arrays birdInfo and animalInfo to loop through all your Objects literal having a "name" property. Then displaying "one alternative" or "two alternative" (sic) is just about playing with array Indexes.